# Send email from external email id such as Gmail, Outlook to Unix user account

Tags: email

I am trying to see if there is any way I can send email from external email address to Unix user account. I don't know if this at all possible or not.

For example, if my external email address is `abc@xyz.com` and unix user name is `test@localhost` on `testserver.test.com` then I would like send email from `abc@xyz.com` to `test@localhost`.

With `mail` command I know I can send email from Unix to my account on Gmail/Outlook but I would to know if any way exists to do reverse. Ultimately I want to have it available in `/var/spool/mail/test` account.

Comment: If you have some mail server, such as [dovecot](http://dovecot.org/) running on `testserver.test.com`, just send mail from `abc@xyz.com` to `test@testserver.test.com`.

Answer (score 5):

To do this you need to have your server 'known' to the internet so that the rest of the world (including google mail) knows where to push your emails. And then run an MTA on your server (like postfix) that the outside world can connect to, to deliver the email. The MTA is then responsible for delivering to the the spool directory.

I am pretty sure that requires a fixed IP address where your server can be reached, and a server that is online most of the time.

If this is only for a single account, it is much easier to create a special email account somewhere (e.g. gmail) and pick up that email with a cron job that call `fetchmail` and delivers to the local MTA. This does not require a fixed IP for the server, nor that the port for the MTA (25) on the server is reachable from the outside world.